# How to add Primary Key to an existing table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table without defining the primary key. When I added values in the table I omitted the field, so all the values for that field was set to `NULL`. When I tried adding primary key to it later by using the following command:

`ALTER TABLE teachers ADD CONSTRAINT pk_teachers_id PRIMARY KEY(id);`

...it throws me an error saying the column has `NULL` values. So I use the following command to set all the values to `1`:

`UPDATE teachers SET id = 1 WHERE id IS NULL;`

This worked and set all the values to `1`, however, I still cannot add the primary key to this field. I am getting error 1064.

I am using MySQL database.

Comment: primary key cannot be duplicate. when you set 1 for the null ids. all null ids get value 1. hence primary key might duplicate

Comment: You may either update PK column setting unique values into it or remove this column and recreate it making autoincrement and primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommended solution - remove and re-create as primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE teachers 
    DROP COLUMN id,
    ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26c8d719ff1e3a77297962029a587b65

Comment: That's what I did. In case everybody is wondering why would I do something like this, I was going through a book named "Practical SQL: A Beginner's Guide to Storytelling with Data" where this was the first thing they did, but in the next chapter it was shown that this table contains a Primary Key. Although it was not shown how. I think I'll drop the book.

Comment: but it could be problematic if there are other related tables.

Comment: @Psycho Relation to non-indexed column with NULL in all rows? seriously?

Comment: sorry my mistake